# Breeze - Saving Entity and Associations

Tags: serialization, breeze

I am having a problem when attempting to save an entity and its associations in one request.

I am trying to do the following:

```
   var myModel = manager.createEntity('MyModel', {
            type: 1,
            attributes: [
                { name: 'one', value: '1', active: true },
                { name: 'two', value: '2', active: true }
            ]
    });
    manager.addEntity(myModel);
    manager.saveChanges().then(function(response) {}).fail(function(e){
        console.log(e.message)
    });
```

On the .NET MVC controller I have something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public SaveResult SaveChanges(JObject saveBundle)
{
    var rtn = _contextProvider.SaveChanges(saveBundle);
    return rtn;
}
```

Everything works completely fine until it is time to serialize the `rtn` variable and return it to the client. I get the following error:

```
exceptionMessage: "The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'."
exceptionType: "System.InvalidOperationException"
innerException: {message: "An error has occurred.",…}
exceptionMessage: "Self referencing loop detected for property 'myModel' with type 'MyApp.Models.MyModel'. Path 'entities[0].attributes[0]'."
exceptionType: "Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException"
message: "An error has occurred."
stackTrace: "   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.CheckForCircularReference(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonProperty property, JsonContract contract, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
↵   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.CalculatePropertyValues(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContainerContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonProperty property, JsonContract& memberContract, Object& memberValue)
↵   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
↵   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
↵   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter writer, IEnumerable values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
↵   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
↵   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
↵   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
↵   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter writer, IEnumerable values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
↵   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
↵   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
↵   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
↵   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
↵   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
↵   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value)
↵   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, Encoding effectiveEncoding)
↵   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, Encoding effectiveEncoding)
↵   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content)
↵   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
↵--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
↵   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
↵   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
↵   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
↵   at System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.<WriteBufferedResponseContentAsync>d__1b.MoveNext()"
message: "An error has occurred."
stackTrace: null
```

This is because the child `attributes` have a reference to their parent and since the parent contains them then the parent ends up having a circular reference.

I thought Breeze would handle this but maybe it does not.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Disregard! I was missing the [BreezeController] decoration.